# How to protect a folder from being copied to USB, DVD, Internet, etc?

Tags: windows-7, encryption, copy-protection

Sort of FBI stuff, but how can I encrypt and prevent users from the ability to copy/move files in a directory to outside the computer? I mean, the program they use reads/saves data into this directory, how to prevent leakage?

Comment: Zero out the bytes, then delete the file.

Comment: If the user's can read the files, they can copy them. You will either have to disable usb storage, dvd writers and internet access completely, or prevent the users from accessing the files. The only other option is security through obscurity, which isn't security at all (make the files hidden, disable directory listing permission, etc.)

Comment: Could the OP (FernandoSBS) please clarify their question?  Are the FBI the "they" you referred to?  Do you know what program is it that "they" use, or even for what purpose?  User gnp is correct - if files can be seen, they can be copied.

Comment: there must exist some software that at least provide some level of protection from taking files out of the environment. The logic clearly says that if the user can read the file he can copy the file, but must exist some sort of software that detect the file content and prevent that content from spreading out of the computer.

Comment: how are they taking and spreading the content? Physical access is stopping usb drives and cd/dvd burners. Cell phones ... cameras.... Internet? By email? You can put something in between that can filter emails for content... and block or reroute the emails. Safest would be no internet at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you mean here, but if you want to keep files and folders on your computer, and limit who knows about them, and who can access them, you might try TrueCrypt, which has some relevant tools.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that you can do that will prevent a person from copying a file 100% of the time, though there are thing you can do to make it more difficult to copy a file (i.e. remove optical drives, disable USB ports, disconnect from Internet, turn off network shares, etc.).  Still, that is not a reliable security measure.  If you care that much about your data then you must always assume the worst case scenario, and the worst case scenario is that if someone had a chance to copy your data then they did copy your data.  With that said the only thing you can do to protect your data is encrypt it.

You don't say in what context you want to protect files.  As [@Charles Lindsay](https://superuser.com/users/51457/charles-lindsay) said [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) is a good choice for whole disc encryption.  [Windows Bitlocker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/bitlocker) is another whole disc encryption option if you have an appropriate version of Windows.  If you only want to protect certain files/directories then there are numerous tools that will allow you to do that.  Pick encryption software that implements known good encryption standards like PGP and strong algorithms like RSA and AES.